# How do I create an ideogram-based 'features' list on nodes?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I'd like to create a simple checklist-style list on a node. How can I do this?

I presume CCK is involved. I'm thinking that it would follow some logic like this: the node editor checks applicable boxes for the relevant feaures. If a box is ticked, then an image is displayed in the list (and so on) on the node.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a Drupal 6 specific answer, that's great, but in the meantime, I would suggest you look at [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/19133/1625). It involves Drupal 7, but the basic principal is the same. If I have had the experience of doing this in D6 I would have added the information to that question, but I have not.

Comment: Some time has passed since my question was posted and I've since upgraded to D7, so that link might be more relevant, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you know a little PHP you can do this with Custom Formatters and/or Display Suite and/or Views PHP. Create the checklist with CCK, then when you render your image, load the node and see if the relevant checkbox is ticked. If it isn't just render an empty string.

http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters

http://drupal.org/project/ds

http://drupal.org/project/views_php

Comment: I don't know much about PHP, but I'll take a look and see what I can learn from those links, thanks.

Comment: Kk, well what you're asking is actually pretty easy if you get your PHP chops up a bit :) hang in there..