# How to create a empty module?

Tags: 8

What is the most basic valid module one can create in Drupal?

It would be useful to have a simple blueprint available, for anyone just getting started with Drupal.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The below instructions allows one to create an empty module, and is helpful for anyone just getting started with module building. If you have troubles getting your first module working, or even showing up in Drupal, ensure you've read all the instructions below.

## Drupal 8

A `project` must at least have

1. A machine name.
2. An [yaml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) info file named after the machine name, in the form `module-machine-name.info.yml` with the following attributes:

   1. `name:` A humanly readable name
   2. `type:` A type, defining to be a `module`.
   3. `core:` The major Drupal core version the module is compatible with, `8.x`, in this case.
3. An empty module file, name in the form `module-machine-name.module`

Drupal looks for modules in these locations, as seen from the web root:

1. `/modules/`
2. `sites/[example.com]/modules`
3. `sites/default/modules`
4. `profiles/[install-profile]/modules`

Technically, Drupal also looks for modules in `core/modules`, but one should *never*, place modules there, hence it's not on the list above.

An example module structure, for a module with the machine name `helloworld`, would look like this:

`/modules/helloworld/helloworld.info.yml`

`/modules/helloworld/helloworld.module`

Notice that both the info and module file as named exactly the same as the machine name, which is important.

The module file may be empty, but the info file must contain a few minimum values for Drupal to recognize it as a module. For our helloworld module, that could look like:

```
name: 'Hello world module to demonstrate module building'
core: 8.x
type: module
```

If you follow the above instructions, you should be be able to get a new module listed in your Drupal site, although it won't do anything, at this stage.

## Drupal 7

A module must at least have

1. A machine name.
2. A humanly readable name
3. An info file named after the machine name.
4. An empty module file.

To be loadable by Drupal, it must also define which core version it is compatible with.

Further Drupal looks for modules in these locations:

1. `sites/all/modules/`
2. `sites/[example.com]/modules`
3. `sites/default/modules`
4. `profiles/[install-profile]/modules`

Technically, Drupal also looks for modules in `modules`, but one should *never*, place modules there, hence it's not on the list.

An example module structure, for a module with the machine name `helloworld`, would look like this:

`sites/all/modules/helloworld/helloworld.info`

`sites/all/modules/helloworld/helloworld.module`

Notice that both the info and module file as named exactly the same as the machine name, which is important.

The module file may be empty, but the info file must contain the humanly readable name of the module, and the core version the module is compatible with.

For our helloworld module, that could look like:

```
name = Hello world module to demonstrate module building
core = 7.x
```

If you follow the above instructions, you should be be able to get a new module listed in your Drupal site, although it won't do anything, at this stage.

Comment: and also `sites/default/...`  just saying ...

Comment: You're absolutely right, fixed it. :) Which reminds me I should check up on the order and make sure it's correct.

Comment: For drupal 8 you now only need the module-machine-name.info.yml. The .module file is not required anymore to have an enabled module. Not that it's very useful but it's possible :)

Comment: D8: .module and .profile files are no longer required. https://www.drupal.org/node/2217931

Comment: Drupal 8: What about `drupal generate:module` ?

Answer (score 8):

For Drupal 8, since the question mentioned a blueprint, I figure I'd mention the [Drupal Console](https://www.drupal.org/project/console) project.

Once that is installed, one can generate module code (and other things like scaffolding for custom entities, plugins, etc).

To generate a basic module from the command line: `drupal generate:module`. One is then prompted through some basic information gathering, and left with the module files at the end:

[image: Drupal console module generation]