# Insert Record Using db_insert in Block

Tags: 7, database

I have created a block whose content uses the PHP as input filter. What I want to do is inserting a record into a separate database.

The code I am using is the following one.

```php
$tracker = array(
  'database' => 'tracker',
  'username' => 'tracker',
  'password' => 'PASSWORD',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);

Database::addConnectionInfo('tracker', 'default', $tracker);
db_set_active('tracker');

$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$finish = $time;
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
$t = $total_time;
$url = $_GET['url'];
$current_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$time =  date("h:i:s");

function is_bot() {
  $botlist = array(
    "Teoma", "alexa", "froogle", "Gigabot", "inktomi",
    "looksmart", "URL_Spider_SQL", "Firefly", "NationalDirectory",
    "Ask Jeeves", "TECNOSEEK", "InfoSeek", "WebFindBot", "girafabot",
    "crawler", "www.galaxy.com", "Googlebot", "Scooter", "Slurp",
    "msnbot", "appie", "FAST", "WebBug", "Spade", "ZyBorg", "rabaz",
    "Baiduspider", "Feedfetcher-Google", "TechnoratiSnoop",
    "Rankivabot", "Mediapartners-Google", "Sogou web spider",
    "WebAlta Crawler", "TweetmemeBot",
    "Butterfly", "Twitturls", "Me.dium", "Twiceler"
  );
    
  foreach ($botlist as $bot) {
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $bot) !== false)
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

if (is_bot()) {
  $isbot = 1;
}
else {
  $isbot = 0;
}

db_insert('ap_visits')
  ->fields(array(
    'id' => NULL,
    'length' => $t,
    'url' => '$url',
    'current_ip' => '$current_ip',
    'user_agent' => '$user_agent',
    'date_start' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
    'is_bot' => $isbot,
  ))
  ->execute();
db_set_active();
```

When executed, the code returns the following error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'c1tracker.semaphore' doesn't exist' in /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/includes/database/database.inc:2168
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/includes/database/database.inc(2168): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
> #1 /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/includes/database/database.inc(680): DatabaseStatementBase->execute(Array, Array)
> #2 /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/includes/database/database.inc(2347): DatabaseConnection->query('SELECT expire, ...', Array, Array)
> #3 /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/includes/lock.inc(167): db_query('SELECT expire, ...', Array)
> #4 /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/includes/lock.inc(146): lock_may_be_available('schema:runtime:...')
> #5 /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/includes/bootstrap.inc(420): lock_acquire('schema:runtime:...')
> #6 /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/includes/bootstrap.inc(442): DrupalCacheArray->set(Array)
> #7 [internal function]: DrupalCache in /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/includes/database/database.inc on line 2168
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'is_logout' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO {ap_visits} (id, length, url, current_ip, user_agent, date_start, is_bot) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6); Array
> (
> [:db_insert_placeholder_0] =>
> [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 1375693838.8169
> [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => $url
> [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => $current_ip
> [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => $user_agent
> [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 2013-08-05 17:10:38
> [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 0
> )
> in eval() (line 61 of /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

It seems that the code is trying to access 'semaphore' table when using the external database.

How can I fix that error?

Comment: This is just a word of advice.  The [PHP module is evil](http://andrewdunkle.com/php-module-bad-bone). There's even (still) talk about [removing it from core](https://drupal.org/node/1203886). I'd definitely suggest spend a few minutes learning about the block hooks and putting this in a module instead.

Comment: I missed that part of the question. @Chapabu is right.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but looking at the database code, there is not manual locking going on, so most likely you have a contrib module that causes the above error.

Regardless, you'll need to debug the `lock_acquire` function to find out which lock is being attempted, and work back from there to understand why the lock is needed.

Comment: Hi, instead of putting it in the block, I transfer it on my theme under html.tpl.php with the same code. Is what I am doing correct?

Comment: Is the code/functionality related to your theme?

Comment: @jaypabs There shouldn't be any logic in `XYZ.tpl.php` files, this should be reserved for modules and preprocess functions :)

Comment: @Letharion the code will simple record the URL accessed.

Comment: @Chapabu did you mean that I should not put in there? Since it returns an error when I put it in block, I consider putting it in my template. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: @jaypabs Yes.  Templates should only be used for HTML output, anything that requires any logic should be dealt with in a preprocess function in either `template.php` or a custom module.  From the looks of it, you would be better off with a custom module.  I'd suggest breaking down what you are *actually* trying to do (without all the DB code) and posting that as a question.  E.g. "I'm trying to track page views, how would I go about it."

Comment: Thank you very much. I will study on how to create a module now.

Comment: @jaypabs http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62471/how-to-create-a-empty-module

Comment: @Letharion thanks. the link is great. Do you have another link that will simply using db_query and db_insert in module?

Comment: Sorry, no such link. :)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, what happens is that the code executes the following query, which doesn't set a value for the *is_logout* database field which has been defined without a default value.

```php
db_insert('ap_visits')->fields(array(
  'id' => NULL,
  'length' => $t,
  'url' => '$url',
  'current_ip' => '$current_ip',
  'user_agent' => '$user_agent',
  'date_start' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
  'is_bot' => $isbot,
))
  ->execute();
```

An internal function in the /includes/database/database.inc file (line 2168) tries to get the database schema, probably to show it in the error message. The function tries to populate the cache containing the database schema data, and that causes the call to `lock_may_be_available()`, which tries to access a database table that doesn't exist in that database.

It's impossible to know which function causes that without knowing the exact Drupal 7 version. It would require to find a version where line 2168 the /includes/database/database.inc file is inside a function/method and, between all those versions, the exact version.

Since the main cause is the query that doesn't set a value for a database field that doesn't have the default value, the fix doesn't require to know exactly which function is calling `lock_may_be_available()`. Rather, it requires to either:

- Change the database table definition for *ap_visits* and add a default value for the *is_logout* field
- Change the query to set a value for the *is_logout* field in the *ap_visits* database table