# Role expiration as PHP condition in Panel pane

Tags: ubercart, panels, users

I use Ubercart 3 for selling site access through roles. Two weeks before the role expires i want to show a button in a panel pane to enable role renewal by the customer. 
There is no visibility condition in Panels to get this done, so i want to use some PHP statement. But i have no idea what this statement should look like. Any clues?

Comment: How does the role expiry work? How would we know when it's two weeks left? The correct solution is to create a access plugin, not use the PHP filter. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/what-are-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc-and-how-does-one-create-them

Comment: Thanx, but that is way to difficult for me. The UC Roles module contains a $expiration variable and [uc_role:expiration:short] contents with which i thought it might be possible to compare the current date + 2 weeks against.

Comment: You should take a look at [How to create a empty module?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62471/how-to-create-a-empty-module/62472) and [What are Ctools plugin (content type, access, etc), and how does one create them](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/what-are-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc-and-how-does-one-create-them/33337). Those two should basically give you what you need to neatly solve the issue. As I have something of a blood feud with the PHP module, I have little interest in helping people misuse it.