# How can I redirect a user after adding a node that also added a new taxonomy term?

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms, hooks

I have a content type with a Taxonomy for locations, these locations can be placed inside parent locations (f.ex United Kingdom -> England -> London), and it is set-up such that the end user can add taxonomy terms that do not currently exist when creating this content.

What I would like to achieve is upon creating a node that ALSO adds a NEW taxonomy term, is to redirect the page to the list of terms page so that the end user can categorise the new location appropriately.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive I understand the *why*, but the redirect-on-saving-new-node-with-new-terms bit should be reasonably straightforward.

I've suggested two possible methods below because the timing of db inserts/updates etc around node creation is a bit intricate, and you may need to shift the task to an earlier or later stage in the process. For example, the API docs mention that the db write cannot be presumed to be complete during `hook_node_insert()`, and it definitely won't be on `hook_node_submit()`. So your mileage may vary :)

You'll need to create a custom module (here's [a stackexchange question on creating modules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62471/how-to-create-a-empty-module) if you don't already know how) that either:

1. implements [hook_node_submit()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7)

   This is the very likely to be the simpler/more reliable of the two methods.
2. implements [hook_node_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7)

   In this method, it is possible that `drupal_goto()` will conflict with the redirect specified in the node form's `$form_state['redirect']`, so it's probably the worse of the two possibilities.

### Method 1: implement `hook_node_submit()`

From inside `yourmodule_node_submit()`, you'll need to:

1. **Make sure that a node with this `nid` does not already exist**!
2. find out what terms (if any) are in the new node (`$node` is passed into the function)
3. load all the terms for the relevant vocabulary, probably with [taxonomy_vocabulary_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_vocabulary_load/7)
4. check to see if any of the node terms are *not* in the full list
5. modify `$form_state['redirect']` if required

See [drupal_redirect_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7) for a bit more information on what happens with `$form_state['redirect']`.

### Method 2: implement `hook_node_insert()`

From inside `yourmodule_node_insert()`, you'll need to:

1. find out what terms (if any) are in the new node (`$node` is passed into the function)
2. load all the terms for the relevant vocabulary, probably with [taxonomy_vocabulary_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_vocabulary_load/7)
3. check to see if any of the node terms are *not* in the full list
4. if that's true, use [drupal_goto()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/drupal_goto/7) to redirect accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I'll give this a shot and see how things go - and in case you were curious as to the _why_, the taxonomies are used to search a database by location, and categorising them into a hierarchy means that it's possible for the user to search a wider 'area'. Is there a module I'm not aware of that would make this a lot easier? What I'm doing presently works but obviously when a new location is added it cannot be automatically added to its correct position in the hierarchy.